# ToExpression and RowBox -- orderings

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, conversion, boxes

With:

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"c", ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]], "a"}]]
```

I get the three elements of the array, but with "a" and then "c" at the beginning. I would like to retain the order as I have input it.

I found that:

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"c", "b", "a"}]]
```

reverses the order, but:

```
ToExpression[RowBox[{"\(", "c", "b", "a", "\)"}]]
```

retains the input order (and removes spaces in between).

However, applying this to my original snippet:

```
ToExpression[
    RowBox[{"\(", "c", ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]], "a", "\)"}]]
```

it comes back with:

```
RowBox[{"c", "\"Private`zztop$3\"", "a"}]
```

(zztop??).

Please help me understand the restrictions here, as well as possible work-arounds.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to use ToExpression?

Comment: This whole thing gets fed back into `CellGroup[ExpressionCell[ ... ]]`. Do you have a different approach?

Comment: [cross posted on community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302184)

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent evaluation/reordering using methods in a linked community topic but since we have an additional feedback here:

> This whole thing gets fed back into CellGroup[ExpressionCell[ ... ]]. Do you have a different approach?

I suggest to keep it low level:

```
Cell @ CellGroupData[{
  Cell @ BoxData @ RowBox[{"c", ToBoxes[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}]], "a"}]
}]
```

Now you can `NotebookWrite/CellPrint` or compose a `Notebook` with this `Cell`.

Comment: Kuba, thank you. I have summarized this at the parallel discussion at Wolfram, [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1302957).

Comment: One last thing (which I will also include in the parallel discussion at Wolfram). Apparently one needs to keep things "low-level" with `CellGroupData[]`, but *also*, for the groupings to work, it needs to be fed back into `NotebookWrite[]` and *not* `CellPrint[]`.